# parsing xml and my code got ugly, any more elegant way to do this?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have the following XML:

```
<propertyMetrics month="12" year="2003" propertyId="3923837">
<metric name="siteTotal" uom="kBtu" dataType="numeric">
    <value>241609.4</value>
</metric>
<metric name="waterUseTotal" dataType="numeric">
    <value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
</metric>
<metric name="propGrossFloorArea" uom="ft²" dataType="numeric">
    <value>20429</value>
</metric>
<metric name="totalGHGEmissions" uom="MtCO2e" dataType="numeric">
    <value>21.2</value>
</metric>
<metric name="greenPowerOnSite" dataType="numeric">
    <value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
</metric>
<metric name="energyBaselineDate" dataType="date">
    <value>2010-12-31</value>
</metric>
<metric name="score" dataType="numeric">
    <value xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
</metric>
```

I am trying to associate the "name" attribute with the "value" element and the "uom" attribute if it exists.

I originally did this:

```
var propMetrics = doc.Descendants("metric")
.Where(e => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Element("value").Value))
.ToDictionary(e => e.Attribute("name").Value, e => new { uom = e.Attribute("uom").Value, value =(double) e.Element("value") });
```

This fails when there is no "uom" attribute. So now I make two LIQN calls and have this much uglier looking code:

```
var propMetrics = doc.Descendants("metric")
                    .Where(e => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Element("value").Value) && !(e.FirstAttribute.Value == "energyBaselineDate") && !(e.FirstAttribute.Value == "score"))
                    .ToDictionary(e => e.Attribute("name").Value,
                    e => new 
                        { 
                            uom = e.Attribute("uom").Value, 
                            value = (double)e.Element("value") 
                        });

        foreach(var x in propMetrics)
        {
            builder.Append(x.Key + ": " + x.Value.value + "<br>\n" + "uom: " + x.Value.uom + "<br>\n");
        }

        var score = doc.Descendants("metric")
                    .Where(e => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Element("value").Value) && (e.FirstAttribute.Value == "energyBaselineDate") || (e.FirstAttribute.Value == "score"))
                    .Select(e => new {
                            name = e.Attribute("name").Value, 
                            value = (string)e.Element("value")});

        foreach(var x in score)
        {
            builder.Append(x.name + ": " + x.value + "<br>\n");
        }
```

Is there a simple way to do this? Possibly inside of a single LINQ query?

Comment: How about just adding a `&& e.Attribute("uom") != null` in your original query's `Where()` clause?

Comment: Funny--I've been living in C# 1.0-land, and your "ugly" code looks downright elegant.

Comment: That is one way to simplify it, I guess I'm always going to need that separate LINQ call though

Answer (score 2):

I would like to suggest that doing complex reading and editing of xml would be far easier using a serialization model. You can easily transform your xml into c# objects, and then edit the object properties however you like. Turning your xml into objects can be done as easily as this:

```
static List<Metric> DeserializeFromXML(string xmlString)
{
   XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Metric>));
   List<Metric> metrics; 
   metrics = (List<Metric>)deserializer.Deserialize(xmlString);

   return metrics;
}
```

Likewise, you could turn your objects back into xml using the following:

```
static public string SerializeToXML(List<Metric> metrics)
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Metric>));
    using (StringWriter writer = new StringWriter())
    {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, metrics);

        return writer.ToString();
    }
}
```

Based on the xml you provided, it looks like your c# Metric object that you will use to serialize in and out of should look something like this:

```
public class Metric
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string uom { get; set; }
    public string dataType { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I was not familiar with serialization so I will have to study up on it

Answer (score 0):

```
var propMetrics = (
    from e in doc.Descendants( "metric" )
    where !string.IsNullOrEmpty( e.Element( "value" ).Value )
    let auom = e.Attribute( "uom" )
    select new {
        key = e.Attribute( "name" ).Value,
        value = new {
            value = (double)e.Element( "value" ),
            uom = auom != null ? auom.Value : ""
        }
    } ).ToDictionary( p => p.key, p => p.value );
```

Comment: This looks like a great idea except I can't get it to compile. I keep getting a "a query clause must end with a select or group"

Comment: Sorry, I guess I've just fixed that.

Comment: Now I get "input string was not in a correct format"... doh!

Comment: I guess that's because you have this: <metric name="energyBaselineDate" dataType="date">
    <value>2010-12-31</value>
</metric>

Comment: The date cannot be converted to double. You have to extend your logic with checking the dataType attribute.

Comment: changing (double) to (string) works... the date value for energyBaselineDate was messing it up

Comment: would you add that logic inside the select statement?

Comment: It depends on your goal. If you need to read the values from that XML only to display them, then you don't have to parse them, therefore you can read any data type as a string. Otherwise, if you needed to implement some processing of the values, you would have to parse them, and then you would have to pay attention to the dataType attribute and plan the structure(s) for storing the parsed values.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, an example of what you are talking about would be greatly appreciated! I do need to eventually parse the data for processing so I'd like to do it all in that one query.

Comment: Then I would maybe create the class hierarchy: class Metric { name, uom } and its sub-classes NumericMetric { double value } and DateMetric { DateTime value }. Also you would need a factory method, which would instantiate one of those subclasses, depending on dataType. Eventually, after reading the XML, you would have a mixed collection of Metric instances. But all that only would make sense if you had to process all the metrics. If you have to process only few specific metrics, I believe you don't have to convert XML to objects. That XML itself is a data storage. Consider XPath for querying.